# Laplacian of divergence equals divergence of vector Laplacian

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose $u$ is a vector including $(u_x, u_y, u_z)$.
Is this correct?

$\nabla^2(\nabla\cdot u)=\nabla\cdot(\nabla^2 u)$

I think it is correct, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

They appear to be the same, expanding out in components.  On either side, for
example, $u_x$ has derivatives $xxx, xyy, xzz$ taken and summed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator), the vector Laplacian reads
$$
\nabla^2 {\bf u} = \nabla (\nabla\cdot {\bf u}) - \nabla\times (\nabla \times {\bf u}) .
$$
Taking the divergence,
$$
\nabla\cdot (\nabla^2 {\bf u}) = \nabla\cdot \nabla (\nabla\cdot {\bf u}) = \nabla^2 (\nabla\cdot {\bf u})
$$
where we have used the fact that the curl of any vector field is divergence-free, and the definition of the Laplace operator.

Comment: @Miraboreasu Concerning your recent [deleted post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4389396/418542), please see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3026071/418542) and related posts on the [characteristics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characteristics)